# Channel addresses after closing connection in Netty 4.0

Tags: java, netty

I looked at some of the source code in Netty 4.0 and I noticed that `AbstractChannel`'s *localAddress* and *remoteAddress* are `volatile`, and not `final`.

Are these addresses guaranteed to be set and available when `channelActive` is triggered?

And, more importantly, what do `localAddress()` and `remoteAddress()` return when/after `channelInactive` is triggered? Do channels *keep* the addresses, even after the connection is closed?

I'm working with the NIO channels, and mostly on Windows, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are set lazy, which means basically the first time you try to access them.